# ORA-00904: "PREV_VAL_R": invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to bulk collect values into a collection. I'm getting `ORA-00904: "PREV_VAL_R" invalid identifier`. The code is simplified.

```
PROCEDURE MY_HELPER() IS
----------------------------------------------------------------
    TYPE PREV_VAL_R IS RECORD( 
            DESC1     VARCHAR2(250), 
            MONTH_VAL VARCHAR2(250),
            MONTH_ALL VARCHAR2(250));
    TYPE PREV_VAL_T IS TABLE OF  PREV_VAL_R;   
                
BEGIN
    SELECT PREV_VAL_R(DESC1, MONTH_VAL, MONTH_ALL)
    BULK COLLECT INTO PREV_VAL_T
    FROM MY_TABLE;
END MY_HELPER;
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `PREV_VAL_R()` as an object constructor, but that is a PL/SQL record type, not something known at SQL level.

You can bulk collect the columns straight into your table of records; though it needs to be an *instance* of that collection type, not the type itself, e.g.:

```
    PROCEDURE MY_HELPER() IS
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TYPE PREV_VAL_R IS RECORD( 
            DESC1     VARCHAR2(250), 
            MONTH_VAL VARCHAR2(250),
            MONTH_ALL VARCHAR(250));
    TYPE PREV_VAL_T IS TABLE OF  PREV_VAL_R; 
    L_PREV_VAL_T PREV_VAL_T;
                
    BEGIN
        SELECT DESC1, MONTH_VAL, MONTH_ALL
        BULK COLLECT INTO L_PREV_VAL_T
        FROM MY_TABLE;
    END MY_HELPER;
```

I've added `L_PREV_VAL_T PREV_VAL_T;` to declare the instance of the collection, and the the `INTO PREV_VAL_T` to `INTO L_PREV_VAL_T` to target that instance. (You can/should use a more meaningful name, of course...)

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=11fe85755dd36b1009f00bcaa33e93d9)

Answer (score 4):

Type `prev_val_r` is a plain old PL/SQL record type, not an object type with a constructor. You can just list the items, without any constructor.

Also, `prev_val_t` is a type, so you still need a variable of that type. I've named mine `t` in the example below:

```
create or replace procedure my_helper
as
    type prev_val_r is record(
         desc1     varchar2(250)
        ,month_val varchar2(250)
        ,month_all varchar2(250));

    type prev_val_t is table of prev_val_r;
    
    t prev_val_t;
begin
    select 'x', 'y', 'z' bulk collect into t from dual;
end my_helper;
```

21c's [Qualified Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/qualified-expression.html) for PL/SQL record types are similar to object constructors, so you could write for example

```
r prev_val_r := prev_val_r('x', 'y', 'z');
```

but they are for PL/SQL only and not SQL. Presumably the PL/SQL compiler builds the code for you internally so it's just [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), and that's why Oracle are careful to avoid calling it a constructor.